# Vertica date series is starting one month before specified date

Tags: sql, vertica

I work with a Vertica database and I needed to make a query that, given two dates, would give me a list of all months between said dates. For example, if I were to give the query 2015-01-01 and 2015-12-31, it would output me the following list:

```
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-03-01
2015-04-01
2015-05-01
2015-06-01
2015-07-01
2015-08-01
2015-09-01
2015-10-01
2015-11-01
2015-12-01
```

After a bit of digging, I was able to discover the following query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('MONTH', ts)::date as Mois
FROM 
(
    SELECT '2015-01-01'::TIMESTAMP as tm
    UNION
    SELECT '2015-12-31'::TIMESTAMP as tm
) as t
TIMESERIES ts as '1 month' OVER (ORDER BY tm)
```

This query works and gives me the following output:

```
2014-12-01
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-03-01
2015-04-01
2015-05-01
2015-06-01
2015-07-01
2015-08-01
2015-09-01
2015-10-01
2015-11-01
2015-12-01
```

As you can see, by giving the query a starting date of '2015-01-01' or anywhere in january for that matters, I end up with an extra entry, namely 2014-12-01. In itself, the bug (or whatever you want to call this unexpected behavior) is easy to circumvent (just start in february), but I have to admit my curiosity's piked. Why exactly is the serie starting one month BEFORE the date I specified?

EDIT: Alright, after reading Kimbo's warning and confirming that indeed, long periods will eventually cause problems, I was able to come up with the following query that readjusts the dates correctly.

```
SELECT ts as originalMonth, 
ts + 
    (
        mod
        (
            day(first_value(ts) over (order by ts)) - day(ts) + day(last_day(ts)), 
            day(last_day(ts))
        )
    ) as adjustedMonth
FROM 
(
    SELECT ts
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT '2015-01-01'::TIMESTAMP as tm
        UNION
        SELECT '2018-12-31'::TIMESTAMP as tm
    ) as t
    TIMESERIES ts as '1 month' OVER (ORDER BY tm)
) as temp
```

The only problem I have is that I have no control over the initial day of the first record of the series. It's set automatically by Vertica to the current day. So if I run this query on the 31st of the month, I wonder how it'll behave. I guess I'll just have to wait for december to see unless someone knows how to get timeseries to behave in a way that would allow me to test it.

EDIT: Okay, so after trying out many different date combinations, I was able to determine that the day which the series starts changes depending on the date you specify. This caused a whole lot of problems... until we decided to go the simple way. Instead of using a month interval, we used a day interval and only selected one specific day per month. WAY simpler and it works all the time. Here's the final query:

```
SELECT ts as originalMonth
FROM 
(
    SELECT ts
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT '2000-02-01'::TIMESTAMP as tm
        UNION
        SELECT '2018-12-31'::TIMESTAMP as tm
    ) as t
    TIMESERIES ts as '1 day' OVER (ORDER BY tm)
) as temp
where day(ts) = 1
```

Comment: You should build out a [calendar table](http://vertica.tips/2014/07/17/creating-a-numbers-and-calendar-table/) otherwise, a SQL solution is available [here](http://vertica-forums.com/viewtopic.php?p=7223#p7223).

Comment: Thanks Kermit, but that wasn't what I was asking about. I was asking about the extra "2014-12-01" that appears at the beginning of the list. As it stands, the problem that prompted the need for this query to be built has already been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it boils down to this statement from the doc: http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SELECT/TIMESERIESClause.htm

> TIME_SLICE can return the start or end time of a time slice, depending
>   on the value of its fourth input parameter (start_or_end). `TIMESERIES`,
>   on the other hand, always returns the start time of each time slice.

When you define a time interval with some start date (`2015-01-01`, for example), then `TIMESERIES ts AS '1 month'` will create for its first time slice a slice that starts 1 month ahead of that first data point, so `2014-12-01`. When you do `DATE_TRUNC('MON', ts)`, that of course sets the first date value to `2014-12-01` even if your start date is `2015-01-03`, or whatever.

e: I want to throw out one more warning -- your use of `DATE_TRUNC` achieves what you need, I think. But, from the doc: Unlike `TIME_SLICE`, the time slice length and time unit expressed in `[TIMESERIES] length_and_time_unit_expr` must be constants so gaps in the time slices are well-defined. This means that '1 month' is actually 30 days exactly. This obviously has problems if you're going for more than a couple years.