# Vertica timeseries seemingly starts on a random day

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a question concerning the TIMESERIES clause in Vertica. Suppose I have the following query:

```
SELECT ts
FROM 
(
    SELECT '2011-10-01'::TIMESTAMP as tm
    UNION
    SELECT '2018-12-31'::TIMESTAMP as tm
) as t
TIMESERIES ts as '1 MONTH' OVER (ORDER BY tm)
```

This gives me the following results:

```
2011-09-30 00:00:00
2011-10-30 00:00:00
2011-11-29 00:00:00
2011-12-29 00:00:00
...
```

Then, if I put 2012-10-01 as the starting date, I end up with the following results:

```
2012-09-24 00:00:00
2012-10-24 00:00:00
2012-11-23 00:00:00
2012-12-23 00:00:00
...
```

As you can see, the first resultset starts on september 30th and the second starts at september 24th. Now I don't really have a problem with it starting in september. I do, however, have a problem with it starting on what seems to be a completely random day depending on what date I decide to start my interval with. This causes problems when the interval decides to start on the 30th or worse the 31st. Basically, all I want is to have my interval start on whatever date I specify like so:

```
2012-10-01 00:00:00
2012-10-31 00:00:00
...
```

Is such a thing possible without doing some ridiculously complex calculations?

Comment: How is this question different from [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33673887/679449)?

Comment: @Kermit I realize my two questions are similar. However, they address two different topics nonetheless. You see, in my earlier question, I merely wanted to know why there was an extra entry in my timeseries. Here it's more specific than that. I don't care about the extra entry at all. I want to know why, when I say "start on 2011-10-01" (as in the first day of the month), the series says "screw it, I'll start on the 30th instead". And then, if I say, start on 2012-10-01 (still the first day of the month, but one year later), the series says "screw it, I'll start on the 24th".

Answer (score 2):

> Then, if I put 2012-10-01 as the starting date, I end up with the following results

Note that both time series (starting at 2012-10-01 and 2011-10-01) produce the same dates. The point of TIMESERIES is to provide consistent intervals between points, which is not possible with Gregorian months.

> Though it makes me wonder why timeseries bothers with interpolating something that's been given outright.

TIMESERIES is not concerned with using the start/stop boundaries you supply it. This particularly would be infeasible when you're expecting jumps by different intervals (actual months).

As I noted in your last question, '1 MONTH' is really 30 days, which leads to problems like this:

```
 2017-01-31 00:00:00
 2017-03-02 00:00:00
```

Where there won't be an entry for February.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
'length_and_time_unit_expression'
Is INTERVAL (DAY TO SECOND) that represents the length of time unit of time
slice computation; for example, TIMESERIES slice_time AS '3 seconds' ...
```

So `INTERVAL (YEAR TO MONTH)` is not supported which is probably why you see funky gaps (my bet is that there is some kind of modulo bucketing going on at the unix epoch value of the date bringing the start date back in time).

You could do something dirty like abuse the timeseries by day to generate a sequence that you add back to the original date.  Cleaner would be to create some kind of date dimension table. Maybe someone has a more clever way than this.

```
select add_months('2012-10-01'::timestamp,timestampdiff('dd',to_timestamp(0),ts))
from ( 
  select to_timestamp(0) as tm
  union all
  select to_timestamp(0) + timestampdiff('mm','2012-10-01'::timestamp,'2018-12-31'::timestamp)
) as t
timeseries ts as interval '1 DAY' over (order by tm)
```

Comment: Yeah, we did end up using a day interval for our query. It proved to be way more stable than using a month interval. You can check it out at [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673887/vertica-date-series-is-starting-one-month-before-specified-date) . Though it makes me wonder why timeseries bothers with interpolating something that's been given outright.

Comment: @Osuwariboy This will give you monthly buckets starting on the day you put in by using `1 DAY` timeseries to generate a sequence that we add back as a month. As for why using `MONTH` doesn't work, the docs say it expects a `DAY TO SECOND` so simply `MONTH` is not supported and I'm surprised it didn't just error out.